# Convert cURL request to Python2 urllib2 request

Tags: python, curl, urllib2, artifactory, python-2.6

I am trying to convert the below code in curl to python2 urllib2 request call for performing a "PUT" operation, it works fine with cURL but i am clueless on getting this converted to python2 code.

> cURL

```
curl -X PUT -u myUser:myPassword -T test.txt “http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/test/test.txt”
```

The problem i face is with the "-T" flag i am not sure how set this in urllib2 call. I tried using Postman for help by adding file to Body->form-data->file

But the code is converted as below which i suspect is not the transfer file call.

```
curl -X PUT \
  http://localhost:8081/artifactory/my-repository/my/new/artifact/directory/file.txt \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 4ffbfca4-a4be-09de-c8ab-0731a2d67009' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F '=@C:\Devops\file.txt'
```

I tried looking at documentations specified here under -T/--upload-file it does not help. Any suggestions.

https://www.computerhope.com/unix/curl.html

https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/options-in-examples.html

Comment: Why not use requests package?

Comment: What part are you confused about here? If you don't know exactly what `curl` sends for this, set up a server (or just `nc -kl 8081`) and look at the output. It should be something like [this](https://gist.github.com/abarnert/0eb457064bf39797b242e071f21c2d1a) followed by the contents of `test.txt`.

Comment: My org has restrictions to pip request ,. urllib2 is available with python2

Comment: Meanwhile, if you know how to use `urllib2` in general, show what you've got so far, and tell us which part you're stuck on. Do you not know how to make a PUT request? How to add auth? Or…?